# How to install chrome extension for all users in ubuntu machine

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I want a chrome extension to be installed for all users in my ubuntu machine and all profile in google chrome. is it possible and if yes then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible.

You need to add your chrome extension detail in /opt/google/chrome/extensions/external_extensions.json file.

Edit that file using your favorite editor then add a line like below.

"thisistheextensionidwhichyouwillgetinext.manager": {
    "_comment": "This is the normal comment",
    "external_update_url": "http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"
  },

While adding the line, carefull about the come as its json file. just validate the json.

Then restart your machine and you see the extension will applied to all users in that machine